# LibGDX - two stages with one camera make the drawing faster

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I read that I can use multiple stages.

I have one `OrthographicCamera` with some custom functions, but they doesn't really matter.

I have a problem here:

```
@Override
public void draw(){
    loginStage.getViewport().setCamera(camera);
    registerStage.getViewport().setCamera(camera);

    loginStage.act(delta);
    loginStage.draw();

    registerStage.act(delta);
    registerStage.draw();
}
```

This is causing that all of the `Actor`'s actions are being performed too fast. It somehow updates the world two times or something. When I uncomment this:

```
//registerStage.getViewport().setCamera(camera);
```

or this:

```
//registerStage.draw();
```

the loginStage is performing well (normally), actor's speed is normal.

**Should I create two cameras for two stages, or is there something wrong in the code above?**

Comment: Your code shown above is fine. Sound like something of yours is monkeying with the `delta` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `camera.update()` in my render just after the code posted above.

The key is here that each stage stores the camera in itself and calls the update:

```
public void draw () {
    Camera camera = viewport.getCamera();
    camera.update();
}
```

so we don't need to call update manually when we did this:

```
stage.getViewport().setCamera(camera);
```

**Camera was being updated twice.**